# Pandas - create new rows with constraints and forward fill them with existing data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. We'll call them main and valid_dates

main:

```
 name    from       amount   days
 A       7/31/18    200      1
 B       7/31/18    300      1
 C       7/30/18    200      1
 D       7/27/18    100      3
 ......
 G       7/17/18    50       1
 H       7/13/18    150      4
```

valid_dates:

```
 date 
 7/13/18
 7/16/18
 7/17/18
 7/27/18
 7/30/18
 7/31/18
```

Here's where it gets complicated. I need to expand the rows where days > 1, but I can't use a non-valid date.

output:

```
 name    from       amount   days
 A       7/31/18    200      1
 B       7/31/18    300      1
 C       7/30/18    200      1
 D       7/27/18    100      3
 ......
 G       7/17/18    50       1
 H       7/16/18    150      1
 H       7/13/18    150      3
```

alternate (and equally valid) output:

```
 name    from       amount   days   rep_days   rep_date
 A       7/31/18    200      1        1        7/31/18
 B       7/31/18    300      1        1        7/31/18
 C       7/30/18    200      1        1        7/30/18
 D       7/27/18    100      3        3        7/27/18
 ......
 G       7/17/18    50       1        1        7/17/18
 H       7/13/18    150      4        1        7/16/18
 H       7/13/18    150      4        3        7/13/18
```

To clarify what happened:

-7/27 + 3 = 7/30. However, no date between 7/27 and 7/30 was in valid_dates, so that entry is left alone with 7/27 representing 3 days.

-7/13 + 4 = 7/17. The only date between 7/13 and 7/17 in valid_dates is 7/16. Therefore a 7/16 entry will be added, and it'll represent one day. 7/13 has to represent 3. Rest of the row data is duplicated.

-Going by the above example. If 7/15 AND 7/16 were in valid_dates, then a 7/15 and 7/16 entry would be added, each representing one day. 7/13 would represent 2. Rest of the row data is duplicated.

**You can assume that where days > 1, from + days will never be greater than another entry in the from column.**

I realize this may be confusing so let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Look only at the slice of the dataframe where `days`>1, sorted in chronological order. Then iterate over it using `iterrows()`. Look at the `from` column and based on the corresponding `days`entry , use the `pd.date_range()` function to generate the range of dates. Filter then from `valid_dates` and you should be able to implement a simple function that modifies the original row in place based on number of available dates and appends a set of new dates as required. The above functionality can also be implemented using the `map` function in pandas , though it can be quite messy.

Comment: Would recommend that you actually try to implement it and then get back with any specific issues to attract answers rather than seeking an entire solution to this oddly specific problem.